# SQL Server 2008 R2 for one of databases access adjustment

Tags: sql-server

I have SQL Server 2008 R2 . I need to create remote access to one of databases on this server. That a user can just edit one of databases and have no any access for another sql server databases or another resources. I created input name on server level. And when I created this I selected from left vertical menu in that dialog box item "Users collation". Then in right upper menu I selected my database (marked left collumn checkbox). I maked that actions and entered with my created input name. Then another databases were not accessable. But system databases (master,model,msdb,tempdb) were accesseble. And were accessable any of another system objects. Such as input name for this account, server roles and another. How I can create acces only just for for my database with no any access for any another objects. What of settings I must adjusted ?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to solve this problem is to go into your security section and right click on the user and select properties. Click on the server roles section and make sure the user is set to public. Then go into the user mapping section and un-check all of the databases you do not wish to let the user view. You can also change the type of account the user has therefore controlling the types of things they can do on that database. Hope that helps.